# Adding List Array item In A Data Table Using Loop Results Error .. 

Tags: c#

I am trying to put the list array(res) item in to the Data Table(_Hdt) using for Loop 
I have put the values in "res" list erray using loop...but this loop results in an error: "variable use asd a method ?"

Here _Hdt and dt are data table and res is list array,

```
for (int r = 0; r < _Hdt.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Select("DATE='" + _Hdt.Rows[r]["DATE"].ToString().Trim() + "'"))
    {
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(_Hdt.Rows[r]["DATE"].ToString().Trim());
        string dateformat = String.Format("{0:dddd MMM d}", date);
        _Hdt.Rows[r]["DATE"] = dateformat;
        _Hdt.Rows[r]["MTU"] = row["MTU"].ToString().Trim();
        _Hdt.Rows[r]["POWER"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(row["POWER"].ToString().Trim()) / 
                                 1000).ToString();
       _Hdt.Rows[r]["COST"] = row["COST"].ToString().Trim();
       _Hdt.Rows[r]["VOLTAGE"] = row["VOLTAGE"].ToString().Trim();
       _Hdt.Rows[r]["KW"] = res(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for incontinent i try to format it before posting but it remained same !

Comment: `res(r)` should be `res[r]`, you're using the wrong array-access-syntax (VB like)

Comment: Please Copy paste it in a note pad to make my code clear.. .

Comment: how do i put res values in _Hdt in this case?

Comment: @ALL thanks all of you for your suggestions ... . res[r] help me out !

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is  res(r) on line _Hdt.Rows[r]["KW"] = res(r);  ??

changes res(r) to res[r]

Comment: res is the list array having values

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* you've just got your brackets mixed up. This:

```
_Hdt.Rows[r]["KW"] = res(r);
```

should be this:

```
_Hdt.Rows[r]["KW"] = res[r];
```

That way instead of trying to call `res` as if it's either a method or a delegate, you're using the [*indexer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

(If so, of course the rest of the code is irrelevant. It's a good idea to cut down the code you post to the minimum possible which demonstrates the problem - and if you've got an error message, quote it *exactly* and show which line it refers to.)

Answer (score 0):

Access the array using square brackets like `res[r]`